# Find whether the largest element in the array is at least twice as much as every other number in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to run a program that finds the index of the number that is at least two times larger than all other number in the array.

Here's my code

```
def dominantIndex(self, nums):

        max_num = max(nums)
        max_i =nums.index(max_num)
        if len(nums) == 1:
           return nums.index(max_num)

        for num in nums:
            if max_num >= 2*num:
                return num.index(max_num)
            return -1
```

However , it doesn't work perfectly for all inputs. Could someone please fix it and check for inputs like :

```
[1,0]
[0,3,4,8]
[0,3,5,2]
```

Comment: Can you please post input and expected output for better understanding?

Comment: Sounds like a question for a class

Answer (score 1):

**This checks for many possible input problems.**

Then it sorts the list to get the answer you are looking for. I decided to sort, for simplicity, but you could use other methods as well. I added comments so everything is clear, especially about the input tests, as asked.

```
def dominantIndex(nums):
    # If the array is empty or None or not a list, return -1
    if not nums or type(nums) != list:
        return -1
    # If the array is of length 1, return the only index, 0
    elif len(nums) == 1:
        return 0

    sorted_numbers = sorted(nums)
    # If the highest number is twice the second largest, return it's index
    if sorted_numbers[-2] * 2 <= sorted_numbers[-1]:
        return nums.index(sorted_numbers[-1])
    else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a library function `nlargest` in the `heapq` module.

```
>>> L1 = [1, 0]
>>> L2 = [0, 3, 4, 8]
>>> L3 = [0, 4, 5, 2]
>>> 
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> def dom_ind(nums):
...     a, b = nlargest(2, range(len(nums)), key=nums.__getitem__)
...     return a if nums[a] >= 2 * nums[b] else -1
... 
>>> 
>>> dom_ind(L1)
0
>>> dom_ind(L2)
3
>>> dom_ind(L3)
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
def check(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return 0
    max_num = max(nums)
    ind = nums.index(max_num)
    updated_array = map(lambda x: x if x != max_num else -1, nums)
    if max_num >= 2*max(updated_array):
        return ind
    return -1
```

Output:

```
check([1,0])
0
>>> check([0,3,4,8])
3
>>> check([0,3,5,2])
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the second highest as well;:

```
def dominantIndex(nums):
    max_num = max(nums)
    secondHighest = max( n for n in nums if n != max_num)
    if max_num > 2 * secondHighest:
        return nums.index(max_num)
    return -1 

print(dominantIndex( [1,2,39,7]))
print(dominantIndex( [1,2,3,5]))
```

Output:

```
2
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate over the list and find the **two** largest elements. Then, if the largest element is at least twice as large as the second largest, you can return its index.

```
def dominantIndex(nums):
    # Assumption - nums has a length of at least 2.

    # Bootsrap the rist two indexes
    if nums[0] > nums[1]:
        max_ind = 0
        next_ind = 1
    else:
        max_ind = 1
        next_ind = 0

    # Go over the rest
    for i in range(2, len(nums)):
       if nums[i] > nums[max_ind]:
           next_ind = max_ind
           max_ind = i
       elif nums[i] > nums[next_ind]:
           next_ind = i

    if nums[max_ind] >= nums[next_ind] * 2:
        retrun max_ind

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think none of the other suggested solutions works if the largest number appears multiple times in `nums`. This does:

```
def dominantIndex(self, nums):
    s = sorted(nums)
    if s[-1] >= 2 * s[-2]:
        return nums.index(s[-1])
    else:
        return -1
```

In addition, you might want to check if `nums` has more than one element.

Comment: What if the last two digits in the sorted array are both equal and at the same time the largest digits too ?

Comment: Well then the largest element of `a` is not twice as large as all other elements. But maybe I misunderstood that - what do you expect in that case? Is the largest number the largest _element_ or the largest _value_?

Comment: Just in case it's the largest value, would you update the value of max_number with the new instance of it at another index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I would simply eliminate duplicates, e.g. by changing `sorted(nums)` to `sorted(set(nums))`.